# TypeError: Invalid shape (128, 128, 2) for image data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spyder, image-segmentation

I write this code and i have an error from one line.
print('Segmented_Test_Mask')
imshow(np.squeeze(preds_test[iix]))

Type Error: Invalid shape (128, 128, 2) for image data

I wrote an FCN model and all the steps are correct, but the image output for the predicted image segment gives an error.

Comment: Please include an [mcve]. Few people have time to make countless guesses and assumptions to figure out what went wrong on your machine.

Comment: Is number of dimensions correct? I think it should be 3 for RGB images and 4 for RGBA.